# Ruby modify and add a hash value in array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to modify an array of hashes using `collect!`.  For each hash I want to add 1 new key/value and modify a different key/value.  However, I'm having problems modifying the existing hash value using `sub!`.  It seems to completely replace the hash with a single array entry equaling the result of the sub! command

```
paths = [{:path=>"bin/ruby/file1", :tag=>"v_10"}, {:path=>"usr/name/subdir/file2", :tag=>"v_12"}]

paths.collect! do |x|
  x.merge(Hash[:file => x[:path].sub(/.*\//,"")])  # Grab file name
  x[:path].sub!(/\/\w+$/,"")                       # remove file name from path
end
```

RESULT:
`=> ["bin/ruby", "usr/name/subdir"]`

DESIRED RESULT:
`=> [{:path=>"bin/ruby", :tag=>"v_10", :file=>"file1"}, {:path=>"usr/name/subdir", :tag=>"v_12", :file=>"file2"}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `collect!`, you want `each`. Collect maps the input hash to the output of each block, and the output of your block is the result of your `.sub` call, meaning you get a flat array of transformed `:path` values.

You can also just set the key `:file` directly rather than building a new hash and attempting to merge it:

```
paths = [{:path=>"bin/ruby/file1", :tag=>"v_10"}, {:path=>"usr/name/subdir/file2", :tag=>"v_12"}]

paths.each do |x|
  x[:file] = x[:path].sub(/.*\//, '')
  x[:path].sub!(/\/\w+$/,"")                       # remove file name from path
end

puts paths.inspect # [{:path=>"bin/ruby", :tag=>"v_10", :file=>"file1"}, {:path=>"usr/name/subdir", :tag=>"v_12", :file=>"file2"}]
```

Comment: `collect!` not `collect`. `collect` would have been fine (with `merge!` instead of `merge`) but a bit pointless

Comment: @muistooshort Either option would have been wrong, he was returning a single value, `x[:path].sub!(/\/\w+$/,"")` from the block

Comment: meagar, thanks for the explanation as to why my code was not working + the answer.  I was under the impression that we could not modify in-place with `each` (hence the reason for my attempted use of `collect`).  How does creating `x[:file]` work here?  Is it because the array entry is pointing to the Hash and that pointer is not actually changing (so `each` works)?

Comment: You're iterating over the array of objects, and each iteration sets `x` to the next object in the array. Objects are assigned by value in Ruby, so modifying `x` modifies the object `x` points to. There is nothing wrong with doing `collect` when you want to leave the original version of the array intact, but you need to return completely new objects or both arrays will contain references to the *same* objects.

Comment: The only reason the block's return value was relevant at all is that he was using `collect!`, if he used `collect` then the block's return value would have been irrelevant. You still have a typo in your answer as your first sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: @muistooshort Ah yes, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Functional Style Version

```
paths.map do |path| 
  parts = path[:path].split('/'); 
  { 
    :path => parts.first(parts.length - 1).join('/'), 
    :tag => path[:tag], 
    :file => parts.last
  }
end
```